# C++ Queue with Linked-list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, queue

Question:

```
struct QueueNode {
    int data;
    QueueNode *next;
};
```

do

- int size() const: return data size.
- bool is_empty() const:
- void enqueue(int val): add a new node to the end of the list.
- void dequeue(): remove the node which head point to.
- int top() const: return the data which will be dequeue next.

This is my code

```
class Queue {
    private:
        QueueNode *_head = NULL, *_tail = NULL;
        int _size = 0;
    public:
        int size() const {
            if (! is_empty())
              return _size;
        }
        bool is_empty() const {
            if (_size == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        void enqueue(int val) {
            QueueNode *n = new QueueNode;
            n -> data = val;
            n -> next = NULL;
            if (is_empty()) {
                _head = n;
                _tail = n;
                _size ++;
            }
            else {
                _tail -> next = n;
                _tail = n;
                _size ++;
            }
        }
        void dequeue() {
            QueueNode *temp;
            temp = _head;
            if (! is_empty()) {
                _head = _head -> next;
                delete temp;
                _size --;
            }
        }
        int top() const {
            if (! is_empty())
                return _head -> data;
        }
};
```

The Online Judge displayed wrong answer.
I think the "int top() const" is wrong.
But I have no idea.
Ask for help.
Thanks.

Comment: What do `size()` and `top()` return when the queue is empty?

Comment: `_head = _tail = n;` should be written as separate assignments. `top()` and `size()` don't return anything if the queue is empty.

Comment: @kaylum needn't to return only return queue isn't empty

Comment: Er, that's not how methods work. If you define it to return something it must do so for every case. Otherwise the result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @dave `_head = n;  _tail = n;` It's ok.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum I should return 0 if no data in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kaylum pointed out, you have not returned the size of the queue if it is empty. It should return 0 in that case, but you have no else part in your `size()` method.

This should probably work:

```
int size() const {
            if (! is_empty())
              return _size;
            else
              return 0;
        }
```

EDIT: Similarly you should return something from `top()` too. If you're using an online judge, then it would have specified what to return in case of empty queues. Read the constraints again please, I guess it would help. It would most probably some exception or some default integer which would be required by the online judge to judge an empty queue's output.

Comment: Why not just `return _size;` without `if-else` at all?

Comment: @Evg exactly my thoughts, but I tried to make minimal changes to OP's code

Answer (score 0):

My answer. Thanks Everyone.

```
class Queue {
    private:
        QueueNode *_head = NULL, *_tail = NULL;
        int _size = 0;
    public:
        int size() const {
            if (! is_empty())
              return _size;
            else
              return 0;
        }
        bool is_empty() const {
            if (_size == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        void enqueue(int val) {
            QueueNode *n = new QueueNode;
            n -> data = val;
            n -> next = NULL;
            if (is_empty()) {
                _head = _tail = n;
                _size ++;
            }
            else {
                _tail -> next = n;
                _tail = n;
                _size ++;
            }
        }
        void dequeue() {
            QueueNode *temp;
            temp = _head;
            if (! is_empty()) {
                _head = _head -> next;
                delete temp;
                _size --;
            }
        }
        int top() const {
            if (! is_empty())
                return _head -> data;
        }
};
```

Comment: 1) `is_empty()` could be written as `return _size == 0;`. 2) `size()` could be just `return _size;`. 3) Prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`. 4) `top()` is still broken. 5) Destructor is missing. 6) ...